# Log-sum-exp trick on a sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, logarithm

What's the best way to apply something like `scipy.misc.logsumexp` to a sparse matrix (for instance a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`), specifying one axis?

The point is to leave the zeros out from the computation.

**UPDATE**

It is better to specify that I'm looking for something that performs the [log-sum-exp trick](http://machineintelligence.tumblr.com/post/4998477107/the-log-sum-exp-trick), doing a simply succession of exp elem-wise, summing the rows and doing a log elem-wise is trivial in `scipy.sparse`. Less trivial is computing in a clean way the max along rows and subtracting it as each element in the a sparse matrix row is subtracted the corresponding max vector elem (retaining a sparse matrix in the end).

Comment: If an equivalent has not been added to `sparse`, then you need to write your own.  For a start I'd work with `np.log(np.sum(np.exp(a),axis=n))`.  If you understand the `csr` data structure, you could operate on its `data` attribute directly.

Comment: you can use that with numpy, which dows not support sparse matrices

Comment: larsman's answer is the kind of use of `data` that I had in mind.  In some cases it's enough to operate on all of the nonzero values; in this you need to select them row by row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-zero entries of a CSR matrix `X` are obtained by

```
X[i].data
```

and (a permutation of) the values of the actual row would be obtained by appending `X.shape[1] - len(X[i].data)` zeros to that.

```
logsumexp(a) = max(a) + log(∑ exp[a - max(a)])
```

for a vector `a`. Let's set `b = X[i].data` and `k = X.shape[1] - len(X[i].data)` and denote our earlier permuted row of `X` as

```
(b, 0ₖ)
```

using 0ₖ to denote a zero vector of length `k` and (⋅, ⋅) for concatenation. Then

```
logsumexp((b, 0ₖ))
 = max((b, 0ₖ)) + log(∑ exp[(b, 0ₖ) - max((b, 0ₖ))])
 = max(max(b), 0) + log(∑ exp[(b, 0ₖ) - max(max(b), 0)])
 = max(max(b), 0) + log(∑ exp[b - max(max(b), 0)] + ∑ exp[0ₖ - max(max(b), 0)])
 = max(max(b), 0) + log(∑ exp[b - max(max(b), 0)] + k × exp[-max(max(b), 0)])
```

So we get the algorithm

```
def logsumexp_csr_row(x):
    data = x.data
    mx = max(np.max(data), 0)
    tmp = data - mx
    r = np.exp(tmp, out=tmp).sum()
    k = X.shape[1] - len(data)
    return mx + np.log(r + k * np.exp(-mx))
```

for a CSR row vector. Extending this algorithm to the full matrix is easily done by a list comprehension, although a more efficient form would loop over the rows using the `indptr`:

```
def logsumexp_csr_rows(X):
    result = np.empty(X.shape[0])
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        data = X.data[X.indptr[i]:X.indptr[i+1]]
        # fill in from logsumexp_csr_row
        result[i] = mx + np.log(r + k * np.exp(-mx))
    return result
```

A column-wise version is much trickier; it's probably easiest to transpose the matrix and convert back to CSR.

---

**UPDATE** Ok, I misunderstood the question: the OP is not interested in handling the zeros at all, so the above derivation is useless and the algorithm should be

```
def logsumexp_row_nonzeros(X):
    result = np.empty(X.shape[0])
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        result[i] = logsumexp(X.data[X.indptr[i]:X.indptr[i+1]])
    return result
```

This is just filling in the general scheme of row-wise operations on a CSR matrix. For column-wise, transpose, convert back to CSR and apply the above.

Comment: Yes it is 'trivial' since you are operating row wise in a pythonic fashion : D Btw, leave the answer as it is and just add the _trivial_ case as an update since it can be handy for others ; )